# Cannot find C++ project templates after installing Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2015

After installing Visual Studio 2015, when I go to File -> New Project, I cannot find any project templates related to Visual C++.  How can I get them?

Answer (score 8):

You can do that by modifying the Visual Studio, and you can do that using these steps:

1. Go to Control panel
2. In the *Add or Remove Programs* dialog box, select the product you want to repair and then click *Change/Remove*
3. In the Setup wizard, click *Next*
4. Click ***Repair***
5. Then *Modify* - now you can select C++ to add it.

Answer (score 7):

Visual Studio 2015 has made a number of setup components optional.  This means that the default installation set is very small and the user can select any additional components he wants to install.  Visual C++ is one of the optional install components.

Most of the optional install components can also be acquired through regular product work-flows.  For example, when you go to File -> New Project dialog and are not able to find any Visual C++ templates, you will at least see an item that allows you to acquire Visual C++ tools.  It does this by launching the setup experience with the "Visual C++" tools pre-selected.

For more information, please see this link:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2015/07/24/setup-changes-in-visual-studio-2015-affecting-c-developers.aspx

Answer (score 5):

You can add the missing templates by:

1. Go to `File`(in visual studio).
2. Select `New project`.
3. Under `Templates` Select ***Open Visual Studio Installer***.
4. Now you can add any component.

**Works on Visual Studio 2017**.
Don't know about others.

Answer (score 2):

If you have an MSVS update 3 installed then you may have face with one of the problem of this update. See more here [Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 Known Issues](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vs-knownissues/vs2015-update3). Here is a quote from this document

> In some cases, applying Update 3 can cause the optional feature selections for Visual C++ (e.g. Common Tools for Visual C++ 2015) to become deselected and uninstalled.