# Cannot create C++ project in Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

I have installed Visual Studio 2015 on my computer and want to use it to write a C++ and C programs. However, when I want to create a new project, I see no options for a C/C++ template. In the installed templates, I only have Visual C#, Visual Basic, SQL server, and Typescript. What should I do to get a C/C++ template now. Thanks in advance.

PS: I found this link where a user had a similar problem, however his fixes didn't work for me. [Cannot find C++ project templates after installing Visual Studio 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31522906/cannot-find-c-project-templates-after-installing-visual-studio-2015)

Comment: so did you run thru the installer again?

Comment: This will probably sound really stupid, but how do I run the installer again?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40313975/23528

Comment: Ok, I think the problem was when I first installed it because when I'm doing that, Visual Studio is opening before quickly closing. Thanks for the help