# Why Visual Studio doesn't install vcvarsall.bat and DIA SDK

Tags: python, c++, visual-studio-2015, windows-10

I'm using Windows10. I have downloaded Visual Studio Community 2015 with Update 3
from [here](https://my.visualstudio.com/Downloads). I've selected `C++ Common Tools` as shown [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35243904/2545680). And they are indeed installed as I can see the system variable

```
%VS140COMNTOOLS%
```

pointing to

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\Tools\
```

But the `vcvarsall.bat` is missing in `VC` directory as well as `bin` folder. How can I get this file and other required?

Also, `DIA SDK` is missing. How can I get this one?

Comment: Visual C++ is not installed by default - you have to select some option or other.

Comment: sorry, didn't understand what you mean, can you please clarify?

Comment: I mean that the default installation of Visual Studio does not include the C++ programming tools - see the following for some fixes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31522906/cannot-find-c-project-templates-after-installing-visual-studio-2015

Comment: @NeilButterworth, yeah, thanks, but I've [checked them when installing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J1aet.png)

Comment: On my installation it is at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat`

Comment: @NeilButterworth, yes, this is where it should be. But it's not there for me :(. Maybe you have a link to the installer you used? Do you use Windows10?

Comment: I downloaded it from MS, no idea of the exact link, and yes I'm on Windows 10.

Comment: do you maybe can share the installer?

Comment: Sorry, no longer have it.

Comment: do you have update 3?

Comment: Just checked it, and yes I do.

Comment: I'd re-install, if I were you.

Comment: yeah, just did, no luck :( i'll try another machine. do you have community edition?

Answer (score 2):

For those with Visual Studio 2017:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build`